# My $(document).ajaxComplete() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm messing with jQuery an AJAX for few days and I've come to a dead end. I'm trying to load some content with AJAX -this part works just fine - and after that I want to execute other script. However, my content loaded with first script doesn't show up till the second script is finished. Code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url : folder,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                        var $codeText = "<li class='ui-state-default'><a href='#' data-featherlight='" + folder + val + "'><img  src='" + thumbFolder + val + "' data-src='"+ thumbFolder + val + "'/></a></li>";
                        $("ul[id=sortable]").append($codeText);
                        $("li").featherlight(folder + val);
                    }; 
                });
            }
        })

$(window).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log("Haba");
    var x = 0;
    while( x < 50000 )
        {
        console.log("Haba nr "+x);
        x++;
        }
```

The whole code is triggered, but images are showing up on website after all the console messages. Does anyone have any suggestion what to do to show up pictures first? I've also tried with done(). and ajaxStop(), still no effect.

Comment: You're blocking the browser from doing anything else (like adding/rendering the images) with the `while` loop

Comment: And I'm trying to find the way to force browser to execute the while loop only after the call is done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move the code you want to run after the pictures are loaded into the success function of the ajax call and do that after the code to load pictures?

```
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        //Code to load pictures

        console.log("Haba");
        var x = 0;
        while( x < 50000 ) {
            console.log("Haba nr "+x);
            x++;
        }
    });
```

I think the reason it's not behaving the way you want it to is because the ajax call is complete after it gets a response back. That response triggers the ajax complete function that runs before your logic in the success function of the ajax call. Also, the way you have it written, the ajax complete logic will fire even if your ajax call fails. Which I don't think you want.

Comment: I mean that I still had to wait till all the code executed for pictures to show up.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that loads the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the .done() function of ajax to get the asynchrone result :

```js
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    alert( "success : " + data  );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Comment: Tried it before, same result - all the code had to execute, then pictures showed up.

Comment: try to use $.post or $.get this is easier to use

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but still - I'd like to know what's wrong with my code :)

Answer (score -1):

try to use setTimeout()

```
function ajaxDone(){
    console.log("Haba");
    var x = 0;
    while( x < 50000 )
    {
      console.log("Haba nr "+x);
      x++;
    }
}
$(window).ajaxComplete(function(){
  window.setTimeout(ajaxDone,1);
});
```